# random UIView switcher

Tags: iphone, button, view, uiview, random

I have three different views in my iPhone app, and when the user presses a button, I need the view to change to either of the three views randomly. I've found this code, but i don't know how to load images..sorry but i'm newbie....!!

```
- (IBAction) yourBtnPressed : (id) sender
{
    int i = arc4random() % 3;

    if(i == 1)
    {
        //load first view
    }
    else if(i == 2)
    {
        //load second view
    }
    else
    {
        //load third view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if view are all in the same viewcontroller you can simply write

```
self.view = firstView;
```

or for more cool transition you can use these method
+ transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:
+ transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:

see apple documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Answer (score 0):

If your views are in a .xib file you can use this code:

```
[self.view addSubview:aView];
```

If you think to create your views programmatically, then:

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
// add contents to your aView here
[self.view addSubview:aView];
[aView release]; // if you don't need it anymore
```